# How do I remove a PFObject that's in a Relation with the current user?

Tags: objective-c, parse-platform, pfquery

This is for an iOS app using Parse as the backend.

The users will get access to a list of `PFObjects` which they can tag to show in a different view. I'm added the object to a `PFRelation` when tagged by the user.

I want the tagged objects to not show on the main list to keep it more user friendly.

Here's my updated code:

```
- (void)objectsDidLoad:(NSError *)error {
    [super objectsDidLoad:error];

    self.objectsToShowArray = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:self.objects];

    PFRelation *relation = [[PFUser currentUser] relationForKey:@"myRelation"];
    PFQuery *relationQuery = relation.query;
    [relationQuery findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *results, NSError *error) {
        // results contains all added objects of current user
        for (PFObject *obj in results) {
            [self.objectsToShowArray removeObject:obj];
        }
    }];
}
```

The user must tap on an object to go to it's detail, from there they can tag it and then go back to the main view controller that has the primary list.

I can see the tagged objects in the results array, it's hitting the removeObject method, but the objectsToShowArray is not removing it so all objects are still displaying.

What am I missing?

Update Two:

I added this code:

```
NSMutableArray *arrayToShow = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:self.objects];

        for (PFObject *object1 in self.objects) {
            for (PFObject *object2 in results) {
                if ([[object1 objectForKey:@"title"] isEqualToString:[object2 objectForKey:@"title"]]) {
                    [arrayToShow removeObject:object1];
                }
            }
        }

        self.objectsToShowArray = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:(NSArray *)arrayToShow];
```

The count is showing that an object was removed, but in my `UITableView` the object still shows.

It's removing the last object in the array and not the matching one by title.

Comment: what happens if you delete using [yourQuery delete:@"123456789"];

Comment: I don't want to delete because Table A will be used by all users. I'd like to be able to tie it in with each user in a way where they can add from Table A to B or C and have those objects be hidden from user interaction for that user.

Comment: how would using the ACL column in the parse table/class to manage the permissions of each row for each table/class help?  The ACL column has read and write permission settings for each row.

Comment: Silly question, but are you reloading your table data after changing the array?

Comment: I am. What's so odd is that in my app it's removing the last item, but I'm also logging out the array and the log shows the correct item being removed.

Comment: I've ran this in both objectsDidLoad and viewWillAppear. Same results.